# github initial upload

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to do my initial upload to github. I think I have everything configured correctly, and I've done the readme commit and origin master push and added my files, but I don't see any changes on github. When I do something like:
`git commit --no-verify -m "some more files for initial add"`

I get:
     `[master 6fcc942] some more files for initial add

     2 files changed, 218 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

     create mode 100755 login_html.php

     create mode 100755 logout.html`

So I think everything is working just maybe not connecting. What should I check? How long should it take?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you push the latest commits to your GitHub repo? `git commit` only commits to your local repo; you have to use `git push` to push the changes to your remote (GitHub) repo.